# Can't create category with id with REST WEBAPI (categoryrepositoryV1/POST)

Tags: magento2, api, rest-api

when i try to call the REST API categoryrepositoryV1 with SOAPUI to create a category (With POST) it says my id doesn't exist.

```
{
  "category": {
    "id" : "16",
    "parentId": 13,
    "name": "Regulateur A127 en ligne, compact",
    "isActive": true,
    "position": 1,
    "level": 3,
    "include_in_menu": true,
    "path" : "1/3/13/16"
    }
}
```

but if I try without and ID , it creates my category.

When I checked where is the error when i try to create my category with and ID , it is because of **line 87/88** in **vendor/magento/catalog/model/categoryRepository**.

it's : `$category = $this->get($category->getId(), $storeId);`

[image]

I comment it in my screenshot.

Why does he try to get the id of the category i'am creating ?

How can I make it work ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score -1):

***Remove id from post parameter & use the below code & check Parent Id as well i have Parent id 1 So its working for me in your case you are using 13 So check it exist or not . Why i removed id from post parameter means its auto generated so need to provided id***

*{ "category": { "parentId": 1, "name": "Regulateur A127 en ligne, compact", "isActive": true, "position": 1, "level": 3, "include_in_menu": true, "path" : "1/3/13/16" } }*

Comment: I need to provide my own ID , that's why i'am here , I don't want to use an auto generated id

Comment: then check your last created id in category section & provided incremented one use below paramenters { "category": { "id": 4, "parentId": 1, "name": "Regulateur A127 en ligne, compact", "isActive": true, "position": 1, "level": 3, "include_in_menu": true, "path" : "1/3/13/16" } }

Comment: I need my id to be a specific number , not an incremented one

Comment: on that case you have to with Custom Api Override the Core Api